# namespaces in main menu of Doxygen documentation

Tags: c++, configuration, namespaces, doxygen

Essentially, I am trying to have "Namespaces" appear in the main menu of documentation for produced by Doxygen 1.7.6.1.

When I use Doxygen 1.4.7, the documentation produced contains the namespaces in the main menu, but when I use Doxygen 1.7.6.1, the documentation produced does not contain the namespaces in the main menu. I'm not sure why this is.

In the configuration file for Doxygen 1.7.6.1, I have set the tag SHOW_NAMESPACES to YES.

Could you advise me on how I might get the namespaces to appear in the main menu of documentation produced by Doxygen 1.7.6.1. Is there somewhere I'm likely to be making a mistake?

Many thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Is the answer as simple as setting the EXTRACT_ALL tag to YES? Is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: What do you mean by "main menu"? Are you talking about the bar at the top of the HTML page?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about the horizontal menu bar in the HTML documentation. Sorry for the lack of clarity. Is there a proper name for this menu?

Comment: This question is incomplete without any actual Doxygen source for us to see. The most we can do is guess as to why it's not showing up.